# A command error "find: missing argument to `-exec'" leads to "bash: cd: too many arguments" when sourcing ./bashrc

Tags: bash, find, arguments, command-line-interface, cd

When I use the following alias by typing ms in the command line,

```
alias ms="find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv \"{}\" ./sure/ \;"
```

I get this error

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Now, whenever I try to source ~/.bashrc , I get this error:

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

... I have to start a new bash shell for me to be able to source ~/.bashrc again without this cd error.

**I'm not sure what's wrong.**

Comment: That alias command looks ok; my guess is that there's something wrong near it (probably in one of the lines before it) that's causing trouble. Try pasting the whole .bashrc and see what it says (if you add the line `#!/bin/bash` before the first real line, it'll give slightly better suggestions).

Comment: Okay so I type #!/bin/bash at the top of my bashrc, but did you mean paste the whole of .bashrc into the command line or here in my question?

PS: I was able to get rid of the  " find: missing argument to `-exec' " problem, by using -t /sure/  and putting {} next to +. 

`alias ms="find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -t ./sure/ \"{}\" +"`

but I still get "cd too many arguments" when sourcing bashrc.

Comment: I meant to paste the whole .bashrc into shellcheck, but if that doesn't spot the problem, adding it to the question (in code format, so it's readable) would let everyone here try to spot the problem. Another thing you could do yourself is to back the file up, then try removing sections and seeing if the problem goes away (the tricky thing there is if you remove something that something else depends on, you may get new & different problems).

Comment: Use single quotes, if you do not need expansion.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Shellcheck is a great utility! Many Thanks... I will try to use this as much as I can.